# Does Kubernetes internal networking keep traffic to co-located Pods where possible?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, dns

In Kubernetes, if I run a Service *Foo* on every Node, and also Service *Bar* on every Node, i.e. with `DaemonSets`. If a Pod from Service *Foo* needs to make a request to Service *Bar*, does Kubernetes networking magic optimise things so communication will be done within the same Node, i.e. without a external network call? Or will a random Pod *Bar* be picked meaning usually *Bar* will be on a different Node, so there will be a network hop?

*Context to question*: I'm thinking to run `CoreDNS` as a `Daemonset`, because with the *cache* plugin, I'm hoping most DNS queries will not need to use the network as there will always be a CoreDNS Pod co-located within the same Node and most requests will be cached. Currently we only run 3 CoreDNS pods and we have 12 Nodes and we see some DNS failures at times of network traffic surges - particularly during a deployment when lot of logging is done, which have to be shipped across the network to ElasticSearch.

---

In case specifics matter:

- The CoreDNS service runs as `clusterIP: 172.20.0.10`
- The services that use CoreDNS run as `type: NodePort`
- The Kubernetes cluster is AWS EKS, v1.14.9. Networking is done with the AWS VPC CNI.

Comment: Have you tried [DNS Auto-scaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-horizontal-autoscaling/) if that all what you need to get past the dns failure during network surge ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Kubernetes will load-balance requests to a `ClusterIP` across all Pods with matching labels (and passing readiness checks). It won't keep traffic within the same Node.

---

Q: So how does the NodeLocal DNS Cache achieve to keep DNS requests local to the Node?

A: When using the NodeLocal DNS Cache, it is necessary to pass a extra arg to the Kubelet of each Node (e.g. `--kubelet-extra-args "--cluster-dns=169.254.20.10 ..."`). This changes the `resolv.conf` of every container in every Pod to use DNS resolver on the Node, instead of a `clusterIP`. The NodeLocal Cache runs on every Node (as a DaemonSet) and uses a arg (e.g. `"-localip", "169.254.20.10"`) to run on the specific IP set in the `resolv.conf` of all Pods. The NodeLocal DNS Cache Pod also needs to be configured with `hostNetwork: true`.

Comment: Thanks @Tom for crisp and Short explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be answered on offcail docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/nodelocaldns/)

> NodeLocal DNSCache improves Cluster DNS performance by running a dns caching agent on cluster nodes as a DaemonSet.
>
> With this architecture, Pods will reach out to the dns caching agent running on the same node, thereby avoiding iptables DNAT rules and connection tracking.
>
> **Having a local cache will help improve the latency.**

[image: []]

Image Reference : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/nodelocaldns/#architecture-diagram

Comment: Thank you. We trialed using the `NodeLocal DNSCache` but found it complicated our network and we saw a increase in DNS timeouts - we never figured out why. I was wondering whether scaling CoreDNS to every Node would give a similar benefit without the increase in complexity.